# Merida Matts TFS 600 original chain lube

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, chain, shimano, lubricant

What lubricant does the chain of a Merida TFS 600 bring from its factory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question can be answered by looking at the product specs. We're a Q&A site, not product tech support.

Comment: @NeilFein: The product specs, say only the original chain is a KMC X10 10s. I saw it on http://www4.merida-bikes.com/en_za/bike/2014/69/MTB+Hardtails/Matts+TFS+600 . If you can say to me where to look at to know the answer, I will obviously thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a chain uses a grease lubricant which is applied hot to the chain into every crevase of the chain before the chain is assembled. Its generally the best lube you can get on a chain, but its impossible to apply at home in the same way (contrary to [sheldon brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/chains.html#factory)) [aside from the fact that that particular formula is likely not sold]. Some more details from Shimano are [here](http://www.bikerumor.com/2011/06/28/chainwear-challenge-quick-interview-with-shimano/).